# I am developing message application in blackberry, but getting stucked with the coding

Tags: java, blackberry, email

I am developing message application in blackberry, but getting stucked with the coding. is there any source code to help me with the same. I referred developers guide, but keep getting error message while debugging.

Comment: Please add more information about your specific error.

Comment: Mm, if you had a general solution to this problem, you'd put us all out of business.

Answer (score 2):

i am not sure but perhaps something like that [how to send the text message to multiple numbers in blackberry java applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680840/how-to-send-the-text-message-to-multiple-numbers-in-blackberry-java-applications) if i got right what you want.